# Single regular expression for find and replace

Tags: javascript, regex

With a single regular expression is it possible to find the erroneous delimiter:

```
Gary Numan- Cars.mp3 // match
Gary Numan -Cars.mp3 // match
Gary Numan-Cars.mp3  // match
```

but not " - ", which is correct.

```
Gary Numan - Cars.mp3
```

So a simple replace can be used to change:

```
Gary Numan- Cars.mp3   --->  Gary Numan - Cars.mp3
Gary Numan - Cars.mp3  --->  Gary Numan - Cars.mp3
Gary Numan-Cars.mp3    --->  Gary Numan - Cars.mp3
```

I've got the following but it matches them all. - I could do it it two passes bit I'm sure it can be now with just one.

Reginald X. Pression where are you?

```
 /(\s{1}-|-\s{1}|-)/gi
```

Comment: I suggest [this solution](https://regex101.com/r/uS4wH1/1).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
/-\S|\S-/g
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vO8fY8/2)

This regex is using alternation to match `-` that is either preceded by a non-space or followed by a non-space.

---

**EDIT:** As per your edited part you can use this `replace`:

```
input = input.replace(/\s*-\s*/g, ' - ');
```

[Replacement Demo](https://regex101.com/r/vO8fY8/3)

Comment: That was fast! Since your using the non-whitespace character either side  - how can you use that as simple replace?

Comment: There was no replacement requirement in question it was only matching requirement.  Can you update the question with replacement for each example?